# Treewidth of a subdivision of a graph

Tags: treewidth

Let $G$ be a graph and $G_s$ its $s$-subdivision, i.e. the graph obtained from $G$ by subdividing each edge $s$ times.

Why is the treewidth of $G$ the same as the treewidth of $G_s$?

(Subdividing an edge $s$ times means that we replace $e = (u,v)$ with a path from $u$ to $v$ of length $s+1$, i.e. $u, x_1, x_2, x_3, ..., x_s, v$.)

Comment: We're not especially looking for posts that are just the statement of some challenge and a request for us to solve it for you.  Where did you encounter this claim?  What have you tried?  What progress have you made?  Have you tried working through some examples?  Have you tried proving it for s=1?   You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: I don't understand your definition of a s-subdivision.  Please [edit] your question to define it more carefully.  How should one choose u_1 ... u_s?  What does that notation represent?

Answer (score 2):

If $G$ is a forest, then clearly the statement is true.

Suppose that $G$ is not a forest, which means that its treewidth is at least 2.  This means that we are allowed to construct bags of three vertices.

Let $e = uv$ be an edge in $G$ and construct $G'$ where we have the path $u, x_1, x_2, x_3, v$ in the place of $e$.  Let $\cal T$ be a tree decomposition of $G$ and let $B$ be any bag that contains $u$ and $v$ (such a bag must exist since $uv$ is an edge).

Add bags $B_1, B_2, B_3$ connected as a path from $B$: $B, B_1, B_2, B_3$.

The new bags are defined as follows:

- $B_1 = \{u, x_1, v\}$
- $B_2 = \{x_1, x_2, v\}$
- $B_3 = \{x_2, x_3, v\}$

It can be confirmed that $\cal T'$ is indeed a valid tree decomposition of the graph $G'$, and the width of $\cal T'$ is the same as the width of $\cal T$.